# Count weekdays within range of time

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I want to specify a range of time and count the weekdays within this range in bash. I found [this snipped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622705) and edited it to print January and February in 2020:

```
#!/bin/bash

startdate=2020-01-01
enddate=2020-02-28

curr="$startdate"
while true; do
    echo "$curr"
    [ "$curr" \< "$enddate" ] || break
    curr=$( date +%Y-%m-%d --date "$curr +1 day" )
done
```

Now I only want to print all Mondays within this range, how can I do this?

I though of replacing `echo "$curr"` by something like: `echo "$curr" | date +%Y-%m-%d-%a` or without echo like: `date +%Y-%m-%d-%a <<< "$curr"` to add the weekdays to the output with `%a` and then filter the Mondays with `sed` or `awk` and count them. Though my approach of formatting the output this way does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
startdate=2020-01-01
enddate=2020-02-28
mondays=()
# what day of week is startdate? Sun=0, Sat=6
dow=$(date -d "$startdate" "+%w")
# the date of the first monday on or after startdate
# if you want Tuesdays, change "1" to "2", and so on for other days.
monday=$(date -d "$startdate + $(( (7 + 1 - dow) % 7 )) days" "+%F")
# find all mondays in range
until [[ $monday > $enddate ]]; do
    mondays+=( "$monday" )
    monday=$(date -d "$monday + 7 days" "+%F")
done
printf "%s\n" "${mondays[@]}"
```

outputs

```
2020-01-06
2020-01-13
2020-01-20
2020-01-27
2020-02-03
2020-02-10
2020-02-17
2020-02-24
```

Comment: awesome, THXAL!

Comment: what is the `mondays=()` for?

Comment: @nath: That declares the `mondays` array and ensures it is empty for its use later in the code.